# Access create method of nested serializer

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a parent serializer that contains two child serializers. The child serializers are re-used and they have logic to update and create.

My request data looks like this,

```
{
 'key1': [
          {'keyA': value},
          {'keyA': value}
        ]
 'key2': [
          {'keyB': value},
          {'keyB': value}
         ]
}
```

These are the serializers that I have written,

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    key1 = Key1Serializer(many=True)
    key2 = Key2Serializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
    ...
```

Child serializers,

```
class Key1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    keyA = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Key1
       fields = ('keyA')
    list_serializer_class = MultipleKey1Serializer
```

```
class Key1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    keyB = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Key2
       fields = ('keyB')
    list_serializer_class = MultipleKey2Serializer
```

List serializers,

```
class MultipleKey1Serializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def update(self, extra_params):
        for el in self.validated_data:
           ... #update logic
```

```
class MultipleKey2Serializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, extra_params):
        for el in self.validated_data:
           ... #create logic
```

This is how I initialize the parent serializer

```
serializer = ParentSerializer(data=request_data)
serializer.is_valid() # <- works perfectly, validates all the fields
```

So the nested serializers validate the data perfectly. Now all I want to do is call the update method inside the `Key1Serializer` and create method inside the `Key2Serializer`.

I tried calling it the lazy way,

```
serializer.data['key2'].create(params)
```

But that's not the right way to do it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: So did you get any error when you tried calling it that way? and what is the error?

Comment: serializer.data['key2'] returns a list of validate data. So calling `.create(params)` on the list give error `list object does not have 'create'...`

Answer (score 0):

So as you already found out, the nested serializer instances are not saved anywhere after validation, so you have mannually create them again. You can do this in your parent serializer's create method:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    k1_data = validated_data.pop('key1')
    k2_data = validated_data.pop('key2')

    instance = super().create(validated_data)

    serializer = Key1Serializer(k1_data, context=self.context, many=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()

    serializer2 = Key2Serializer(k2_data, context=self.context, many=True)
    serializer2.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer2.save()

    return instance
```

Comment: Is there a way I can save the instance when it was first created?

Comment: @dhiraj I don't think it makes any much sense to do that in the case of an update because they are initialized without a model instance just purely for validating the nested data. They are initiated the same time that each field is validated so you can try to check out `is_valid()` to see how each field (serializers are also fields there) are initialized during validation. You'd have to determine which nested fields are serializers and save the instances somewhere in the parent serializer